# Ember.js - Can't access loaded record

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to change the header of my RESTAdapter after I loaded the user, but can't access the properties.

Any Ideas why ?

The related Code:

```
var user = '';
App.MainRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(params){
    user = this.store.find('user',{email: params.email});
    alert(user.hash); //get a undefined
    return user;
},
actions:{
    addList: function(){
        var list = this.store.createRecord('list', {
            name: 'New list',
            desc: 'Describe it here'
        });
        this.store.find('user', 1).then(function(user){
            list.set('user', user);
        })
        list.save();
    }
}
})
```

The Json Response on `this.store.find('user', {email: params.email});`:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "hash": "66ff7d6eae591ca2a7d6b419991690e8",
      "email": "marvin@blabla.de",
      "name": "",
      "lists": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Model definitions: https://gist.github.com/Osile/5544ccab1997c4da2b5b

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: You define `DS.Model` for `user` and `list` somewhere? Could you share the code?

Comment: Added them as a gist caused by stackoverflow's too much code rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return a Promise in Model, but you can also access it earlier. Code:

```
model: function(params){
    users = this.store.find('user', { email: params.email }); // returns promise
    users.then(function(item) { // resolves promise
        user = item.get('firstObject');
        alert(user.get('hash'));
    });
    return users; // model will wait for data
}
```

It works. You can use following Handlebars.js template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="main">
    From model:
    <ul>
    {{#each}} <!-- Iterate over array resolved from promise. -->
        <li>{{hash}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Complete code: [emberjs.jsbin.com](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wiyesoca/4#/main/marvin@blabla.de)

Comment: For instance this helped me a lot but after solving my problem I can't access the model from my html code anymore.. It wasn't even assigned or listed in the Ember Inspector

Comment: After a little investigation I figured out that return is called before the record is loaded and I can't call return from inside the `.then` callback..